# How do I successfully build OpenSSL 0.9.8 on MacOS Mojave?

Tags: xcode, openssl, clang, macos-mojave

I first attempted this by getting the stock source from OpenSSL's website. That wasn't fun.

Then I clued in, and [I got the source from here](https://opensource.apple.com/releases/).

When I try to build from Xcode, it fails with several warnings and 1 error.

```
/Users/x/OpenSSL098-OpenSSL098-76.200.2/src/crypto/x509/x509_vfy_apple.c:29:10: Did not find header 'TrustEvaluationAgent.h' in framework 'TrustEvaluationAgent' (loaded from '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks')
```

I had assumed that the patches included in this tarball were already applied, and when I attempt to run the bash script to do that, it complains that there is no (openssl) source tarball... that's ok (I think), there is already a populated src/ directory. I modified the bash script enough that it would ignore that, and indeed, when it goes to patch it gripes the patches are already applied. The README.rtf file (Apple's) is suggestive that this is only if I wish to use the patches against a later version of the source, which I'm not much interested in.

It's not clear to me if my Xcode is just mangled beyond recognition, if I'm missing some dependency, or if I don't know what I'm doing within the Xcode interface (much more comfortable on the command line).

I did [find this](https://github.com/wanttobeno/Openssl_for_mac/tree/44f34d051627f31c8d55920793654eedae0f917f), which seems like a related issue... but I cannot find the source code he suggests needs to be uncommented (nor how to remove the references from the project file).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

But for the unclear English, the instructions in the [second link](https://github.com/wanttobeno/Openssl_for_mac/tree/44f34d051627f31c8d55920793654eedae0f917f) are correct.

Delete the x509_vfy_apple.c file from the treeview on the left, it will be in the Source/crypto/x509 folder. Then in x509_vfy.c (same folder), there will be an #if directive near line 76. It's defined as...

```
#if __APPLE__
```

Make that...

```
#if 0
```

Somehow I brainfarted on this and made it `#if 1` on the first try, and then dismissed the instructions as not working. Commenting this out would also work, or just nuking the entire directive for that matter.

Still seems to compile with a zillion warnings, but I'm not even sure that just isn't what you get with a 7 year old version of openssl.